# can't able to connect to osquery daemon using python

Tags: python, thrift, osquery

I am trying to use evented tables of osquery using python but I am getting an exception. How can I use evented tables.

```
import osquery

if __name__=="__main__":

 instance= osquery.ExtensionClient('\\.\pipe\osquery.em')
 instance.open()
 
 while True:
  client=instance.extension_client()
  results=client.query("SELECT * FROM ntfs_journal_events;")
  if(results.response):
   print(results.response)
   break
 instance.connection=None
```

The error I am getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Yash\OneDrive - Incrux Technologies Private Limited\Desktop\Incrux\osquery3.py", line 11, in 
> results=client.query("SELECT * FROM _events;")
> File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\osquery\extensions\ExtensionManager.py", line 181, in query
> self.send_query(sql)
> File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\osquery\extensions\ExtensionManager.py", line 190, in send_query
> self._oprot.trans.flush()
> File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\thrift\transport\TTransport.py", line 179, in flush
> self.__trans.write(out)
> File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\osquery\TPipe.py", line 126, in write
> raise TTransportException(
> thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Called read on non-open pipe

Comment: Does it work on a non-evented table?

Comment: No, it gives same exception.

Comment: Is there any other method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`Called read on non-open pipe` sounds like osquery isn't listening on that pipe. Is osquery running? Are you sure that's the socket path?